# How to keep the same button style after being pressed?

Tags: java, android, oop, android-studio

When I click one of the buttons (forgot your code?), it displays solid red colour and lead to a different activity. When I return to the previous activity, the button has changed to default style and is displaying orange colour when pressed. How do I retain the button's original style and state after being pressed for the first time?

**Button State xml file:**

```
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
        <corners android:radius="3dip" />
        <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#000000" />
        <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#FF0D00" android:endColor="#FF0D00"  />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_focused="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="3dip" />
        <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#000000" />
        <solid android:color="#FF0D00"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
        <corners android:radius="3dip" />
        <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#000000" />
        <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#D8D8D8" android:endColor="#848484" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

**Screenshots:**
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you should override the onResume() method for your activity and change the button color to gray programmatically inside it. Or you can finish() your activity after start the next activity, so when you go back, the activity will restart and the buttons should be like when you start for the first time.